Problemas al generar PDF desde una URL con Django
Hola que tal ? tengo que generar un PDF a traves de una url proporcinada por el cliente (Esta URL es de un reporte de PowerBi que fue proporcionada con este formato app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiODEyNjgyNDUtZjY2NS00NmZiL.....) ya tengo el proceso realizado y este es mi código:
para que se entienda el contexto del código, la variable llamada PDF es la que guarda la url obtenida.

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pdfkit,uuid


def descargar_pdf(request,urls):
    query_param = request.GET.get("r")
    URL = urls
    PDF = URL+'?r='+query_param
   
    nombre_archivo = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".pdf"

    opciones = {'load-error-handling': 'ignore',
                'javascript-delay': 2000,
               
            }

    pdfkit.from_url(PDF,nombre_archivo,options=opciones)

    try:
        with open(nombre_archivo,'rb') as pdf_file:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf_file.read(),content_type='application/pdf')
            response ['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'+ nombre_archivo + '"'
             
            return response
    except IOError as err :
        return HttpResponse("No se pudo generar el archivo a descargar: "+err)
        #return render(request, "index.html",{"param":PDF})

Entonces al generar la descarga de mi reporte en formato PDF se descarga normalmente pero la vista del pdf es la que adjunto en la imagen.

y lo que necesito es que se genere el pdf con el contenido del reporte y no lo que aparece en la imagen adjunta.
tengo instalados los paquetes pdfkit y wkhtmltopdf
Alguien amable que me pueda ayudar u orientar en este tema. por favor !!!
de antemanos muchas gracias.
